# Kibana chart time range - how to auto-dynamically set it?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create a Kibana TSVB visualization that displays an “events per second (EPS)” metric for the last created elasticsearch index of a particular index pattern.  Currently I’m using a Count aggregator that pipes to the Math aggregator with the formula `params.Count / (params._interval / 1000)`.

But this calculation is only accurate if the chart’s timerange is set to exactly the first and last timestamps in the index. Otherwise the empty data sets (both before and after the index’s timeframe) is being included in calculating the EPS. Currently I have to manually query the min/max timestamps of the index and then manually set the chart’s timeframe in the upper right corner to match that, only then it calculates the EPS correctly.

So my question… is there a way to automatically do this?  Such as having the chart’s Start and End timerange as variables equal to the Min and Max timestamps of the particular index I’m looking at?  Or have it ignore the out of bounds time range?

Thanks